# Confusions regarding the Lorentz force

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, lorentz-symmetry, magnetic-moment

- **Why magnetic force isn't doing any work I know it's a similar case to centripetal force but can someone give me best possible answer not giving the dot product analogy but some high level mathematical proof and a useful analogy**
- Why charge doesn't speed up or speed down because of magnetic force because if magnetic field is acting like a **Potential field** then charge velocity should change e.g in projectile motion when taken in potential field it's independent axes of motion become dependent on each other[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the work is $\int (\int\rho(E+\frac{\partial r}{\partial t}\times B)\cdot dr)dV=\int( \int\rho E\cdot dr)dV$ since (if I understand correctly) dr points in the same direction as $\frac{\partial r}{\partial t}$ and the cross product makes the resulting vector normal to dr (and B too for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

> Why charge doesn't speed up or speed down because of magnetic force
>   because if magnetic field is acting like a potential field then charge
>   velocity should change

The charge *velocity* does change but the charge does not speed up (or slow down).  The component of the magnetic force *parallel* to the velocity is zero and thus, only the *direction* of the velocity changes, not the *magnitude* (speed).

> Why magnetic force isn't doing any work I know it's a similar case to
>   centripetal force but can someone give me best possible answer not
>   giving the dot product analogy

If the charge does not speed up (or slow down), the kinetic energy of the charge does not change - KE depends on the *magnitude* of the velocity (squared) - and thus, no work is done on or by the charge by the magnetic force.

> but some high level mathematical proof

Why???

Comment: I require high mathematical proof because I think it's the place where symmetry of physics lies it would help me look at this concept a lot better

Comment: So can you modify the answer now

Comment: @user112820, it doesn't work that way here.

Comment: I have modified my question now can you give me a better answer